# Number of continuous functions, analysis question.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How many different continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exist for which

$$ (f(x))^2 = x^2,\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}? $$

I'm pretty sure there are only 4 $f(x) = x, -x,|x|,$ and $-|x|$, but is this correct and how would I actually show this?

Comment: Take square root on both sides and show that $f$ cannot change sign anywhere except for $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it from the comment.

$f(x) = \pm x$. Therefore $f$ can only change sign when $x = 0$, which leaves the 4 cases from the original post.

Comment: For $x\ne 0$  let $g(x)=f(x)/|x|$ ,which is continuous on $ R$   \    $ \{0\}$, but $g(x)\in \{-1,1\}$ for $x\ne 0.$  If $0<a<b$ and $g(a)\ne g(b)$ then $\{g(x):a\leq x\leq b\}\supset [-1,1],$ which is absurd. So $  g$ is constant on  $(0,\infty).$

Answer (score 0):

since $(f(x))^2=x^2 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ therefore$f(0)=0$
consider $f$ on $l=(0,\infty)$ 
$f(x)\neq0$ as $f^2\neq 0$ then $\forall x \in l$
$f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$ (because $f(x)$ is continuos at zero therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=f(0)$)
Thus you get two functions.O ther two can be obtained from other interval appllying same arguement.